# Conditional expectation - a functional analytic proof of existence?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, duality-theorems

$
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbf{E}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathscr{F}}
\newcommand{\scrG}{\mathscr{G}}
$Let $(\Omega,\scrF,\pp)$ be a probability space and let $\scr{G}\subset\scrF$ be a $\sigma$-subalgebra. Let $X$ be a real, integrable $\scrF$-measurable random variable. A [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) of $X$ relative to $\scrG$ is any real, integrable $\scrG$-measurable random variable $Y$ such that
$$\forall A\in\scrG,\quad\E[1_AX]=\E[1_AY]$$
Existence is usually proven by invoking the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem): the correspondence $A\mapsto\E[1_AX]$ defines a signed measure on $\scrG$; it is clearly absolutely continuous with respect to (the restiction to $\scrG$ of) $\pp$, hence is of the form $Y\cdot\pp$ for a uniquely defined $Y\in\ L^1(\scrG)$.

> **Question:** Is there a "functional analytic" proof of this fact?

By this I mean a proof along the lines of

1. give an abstract characterization of the continuous linear maps $L^\infty(\scrG)\to\R$ that are of the form $Z\mapsto\E[YZ]$ for some $Y\in L^1(\scrG)$,
2. show that the continuous linear form $L^\infty(\scrG)\to\R, Z\mapsto\E[ZX]$ satisfies this criterion, and is thus of the form $Z\mapsto\E[ZY]$ for a uniquely determined $Y\in L^1(\scrG)$.

Another way of formulating the first question is "how does one recognize continuous linear forms on $L^\infty(\scrG)$ that arise from the canonical embedding $L^1(\scrG)\to L^1(\scrG)''\simeq L^\infty(\scrG)'$ under the identification $L^\infty(\scrG)\simeq L^1(\scrG)'$, where $V'$ is the topological dual of the topological vector space $V$.

---

I'm wondering whether the Radon-Nikodym theorem is a secretly a result characterizing those continuous linear forms on $L^\infty(\scrG)$ that arise from the embedding $L^1(\scrG)\hookrightarrow L^\infty(\scrG)'$. The characterization of absolutely continuity of measures $\mu$ through $\pp(A)=0\implies\mu(A)=0$ is seemingly useless in this scenario, as $1_A$ for $A$ a $\pp$-nullset are zero in $L^\infty$. The characterization of absolute continuity of nonnegative measures $\mu$ through
$$\forall\epsilon>0~\exists\delta>0~\forall A\in\scrG~\Big(\pp(A)<\delta\implies\mu(A)<\epsilon\Big)$$
seems more suited for this purpose as a kind of equi-integrability condition on a continuous linear form $L^\infty\to\R$.

Comment: RNT itself has  a FA proof. Rudin uses Hilbert space theory to prove this theorem. Also conidtional expectation is a projection opertator on $L^{2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That's a good point. I'm addressing it in a comment to Lars' answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward functional analytic argument if you restrict yourself to $L^2(\mathcal{F})$ rather than $L^1(\mathcal{F})$.

If you consider $L^2(\mathcal{G}) \subset L^2(\mathcal{F})$ for the sub sigma algebra $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ then $Z \mapsto E[ZX]$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^2(\mathcal{F})$ for any $X \in L^2(\mathcal{F})$ where $X$ is the gradient guaranteed by Reisz representation theorem. Now, note that $Z \mapsto E[ZX]$ is also a continuous linear functional on $L^2(\mathcal{G})$. Thus, by Reisz representation theorem, there exists some $E[X|\mathcal{G}] \in L^2(\mathcal{G}) $ such that $E[ZX] = E[Z E[X|\mathcal{G}]]$ for all $Z \in L^2(\mathcal{G})$.

The answer to the following question discusses the $L^1$ to $(L^{\infty})^*$ embedding map and its pseudo-inverse:
[The Duals of $l^\infty$ and $L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/the-duals-of-l-infty-and-l-infty)

This might also be relevant: [Is there a Banach space version of Riesz representation theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296087/is-there-a-banach-space-version-of-riesz-representation-theorem)
[https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/4-06-dual-lp.pdf](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/real-an/4-06-dual-lp.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. This proof extends to prove existence of conditional expectations for $X\in L^p(\mathscr{F})$ for $1<p<+\infty$: the map $L^q(\mathscr{G})\to\Bbb{R}, Z\mapsto\mathbf{E}[ZX]$ is continuous by Hölder's inequality and thus of the form $Z\mapsto\mathbf{E}[ZY]$ for a uniquely determined $Y\in L^p(\mathscr{G})$ by $L^p$-$L^q$ duality. But is there a proof that works for $L^1$ ?

Comment: This might work: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-10/S0002-9939-96-03493-4/S0002-9939-96-03493-4.pdf

Comment: What does "cabv" stand for (first reference) ?

Comment: Regular borel measures I think, but the reference I added to my post is what you want.

Comment: I'm going through these notes. I can only see Exercise 2. B (p. 310-311) as being relevant, but they also use Radon-Nikodym.

Comment: Theorem 6.1 doesn't cover the case of continuous linear maps $L^\infty\to\Bbb{R}$ as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, my question asks about continuous linear forms $L^\infty\to\Bbb{R}$ and for a criterion to recognize them as coming from som $Y\in L^1$.

Comment: The ``duals of $\ell^\infty$ and $L^\infty$'' link is pretty relevant, thanks!